# Applying a simple cache to all functions in a python package after import

Tags: python-3.x, caching, simulation, python-decorators

I have a continuous simulation model that is composed of hundreds of python functions across several modules in a python package, each a which represent a model component in the form of `y = f(t)` where `t` is the current model time.

In a given time step these functions are called several times across the other functions so it would make sense to have an extremely simple cache that will save the function result of the current time step. I have two questions:

1. How can I apply a cache to all functions in the python package?
2. How should the cache be defined?

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Imports all functions in the python package 
# (__init__.py start imports them)
import model

def cache(f):
    t1 = None
    y = None
    def cached_func(t2):
        if t1 != t2:
            t1 = t2
            y = f(t2)
        return y
    return cached_func

# Iterate through each function and apply the cache
for name, obj in model.__dict__.items():
    obj = cache(obj)
```

I guess I've implemented the cache as a sort of decorator, but I am not applying it with the `@decorator` syntax as it will add hundreds of lines to the model code. Instead I am doing it before the model is integrated.

When I test out the `cache` function and call the result I end up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pbreach\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-c0c62e8a0eaa>", line 1, in <module>
    cached_test_func(3)
  File "<ipython-input-9-780e50b4626f>", line 5, in cached_func
    if t1 == t2:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 't1' referenced before assignment
```

Which probably makes sense but I figured that t1 would act as a global to `cached_func`.

My second concern is that the model functions won't actually be modified as they will be called from other functions that have already been imported in the line `import model`. Is this true and how would I be able to get around this other than decorating all of the functions in their respective files?